# Technique for stem cell isolation

Tags: wo2012168930a3

In reference to the patent: [WO2012168930A3](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2012168930A3)

I would like to know if the fact to isolate the stem cells and grow them in organoids is forbidden without an authorization. 
I mean : 
In this patent we understand that if we grow stem cells in organoids we need a special medium, and in this case it's protected. But, is the fact to take out the the crypt, isolate the stem cells and culture them with a commercialized medium is authorized ?

Comment: Could you please tell us what country you are in?

Answer (score 1):

The document you linked to is an application, not a patent. I looked and there is at least one patent currently granted associated with this application. It is [EP2718422B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2718422B1/en). It is important to use actual patents where possible as the claims in applications may be far broader than the resulting patent. Also patents apply to specific countries so whether or not a patent applies to you can depend on the country you are in.

As for your specific question, this patent is outside my field of expertise. What is important to understand is that the claims define what is protected by the patent. To infringe on a patent, you must implement each and every aspect of at least one claim. The patent has only one independent claim and 25 dependent claims. The independent claim is as follows.

> 1. A culture medium for expanding a population of adult epithelial stem
>      cells, wherein said culture medium comprises a basal medium to which
>      is added:
>
>    i. an agonist of Lgr5;
>
>    ii. a BMP inhibitor; and
>
>    iii. one or
>      more TGF-beta inhibitor, which binds to and reduces the activity of
>      ALK5, ALK4 and/or ALK7.

This claim seems specific to the culture medium and doesn't cover anything else so I would guess if you used a commercial culture medium that doesn't infringe on this claim you would be OK. Regardless, I must advise that I am not a patent attorney and this is not legal advise. There is always the potential for other patents to be applicable.